# PHP Entering if-condition without meeting criteria

Tags: php

Working on saving the value of checkboxes in a database. I have 3 variables (`$user_id, $checkbox_id, $checked`) but only the 3rd one is important.

`$checked` is either true or false to signal if the user checked or unchecked the checkbox. The following code is just the relevant stuff:

```
$checked = $_POST['checked'];

$check_interests_query  = "SELECT All interests from interests Table";
$run_query = mysqli_query($connect, $check_interests_query);

$status_1 = $checked;

if(mysqli_num_rows($run_query) == 0 && $checked == true){
   $in = "first";
   //do stuff
}

else if(mysqli_num_rows($run_query) != 0 && $checked == true){
  $status_2 = $checked;
  $in = "second";
  //do stuff
}

//Other conditions
```

So now I check and uncheck the same checkbox and get the following results..

When checking the checkbox:

```
$checked = true
$in = "second"
$status_1 = true
$status_2 = true
```

When unchecking the checkbox:

```
$checked = false
$in = "second"
$status_1 = false
$status_2 = false
```

So `$checked`, is false when the document begins, false before the if-condition and false after entering the condition. It enters said condition despite the condition clearly dictating to only play out when `$checked` is true.

What did I miss?

Edit: `var_dump($_POST)` gives out the following

When checking the checkbox:

```
array(3) {
  ["checked_id"]=>
  string(1) "3"
  ["checked"]=>
  string(4) "true"
  ["user_id"]=>
  string(1) "6"
}
```

When unchecking it:

```
array(3) {
  ["checked_id"]=>
  string(1) "3"
  ["checked"]=>
  string(5) "false"
  ["user_id"]=>
  string(1) "6"
}
```

Comment: What are your raw `$_POST` values?

Comment: var_dump is your friend :) It shouldn't be hard to figure it out

Comment: An unchecked checkbox isn't false. it's unset.

Comment: I would use `$checked = isset($_POST['checked']);`

Comment: @RobbieAverill When checking the checkbox: `true`when unchecking `false`

Comment: var_dump($_POST); and edit your question with result of that

Comment: @Cid this is a PHP File that gets executed by AJAX whenever a checkbox is clicked. I check with `.prop()` if its checked or not and send a `true` when it is and a `false` when it isnt.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/language.operators.comparison.php - check difference between `==` & `===`

Comment: `$_POST` values are strings.  Try this fun example `var_dump('false' == true);` to see the result :)

Comment: Would you `gettype($checked)` ?

Comment: @timclutton Yeeeep *JUST* noticed that. Thanks for the help. God...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The POST parameters you get are strings.

If you have "true" or "false" as strings in your POST variable, you should `json_decode` it to have it translated to boolean.

Change your first line with:

```
$checked = json_decode($_POST['checked']);
```

or, to be safer:

```
$checked = $_POST['checked'] == "true";
```

This last will set `$checked` as true if the string "true" is contained in the POST variable.

Comment: to add to this answer: checking for `=== "true"` would also work